# File Binary vs Text

Tags: c++, file

Are there some situation where I have to prefer binary file to text file? I'm using C++ as programming language?

For example if I have to store some large text file is it better use text file or binary file?

**Edit**

The file for the moment has no requirment to be readable from human. Are some performance difference, security difference and so on?

**Edit**

Sorry for the omit other the requirment (thanks to Carey Gregory)

- The record to save are in ascii encoding
- The file must be crypted ( AES )
- The machine can power off any time. So I've to try to prevents errors.
- I've to know if the file change outside the program, I think I'll use a sha1 digest of the file.

Comment: Why don't you simplify the question and just tell us what your requirements are?

Comment: If your data is ASCII text, then why would you want to store it as anything else?  Unless you have a requirement such as compression or encryption, there's no reason to change the encoding of your data, and many good reasons not to.

Comment: Anotother requirment is encryption (AES)

Comment: Wow, a rather major requirement to omit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a general rule, define a text format, and use it.  It's much
easier to develop and debug, and it's much easier to see what is
going wrong if it doesn't work.

If you find that the files are becoming too big, or taking to
much time to transfer over the wire, consider compressing them.
A compressed text file is often smaller than you can do with
binary.  Or consider a less verbose text format; it's possible
to reliably transmit a text representation of your data with
a lot less characters than XML uses.

And finally, if you do end up having to use binary, try to chose
an existing format (e.g. Google's protocol blocks), or base your
format on an existing format.  Just remember that:

- Binary is a *lot* more work than text, since you practically
  have to write all of the `<<` operators again, including those
  in the standard library.
- Binary is a *lot* more difficult to debug, because you can't
  easily see what you've actually done.

Concerning your last edit:

- Once you've encrypted, the results will be binary.  You can
  use a text representation of the binary (base64 or some such),
  but the results won't be any more readable than the binary, so
  it's not worth the bother.  If you're encrypting in process,
  before writing to disk, you automatically lose all of the
  advantages of text.
- The issues concerning powering off mean that you *cannot* use
  `ofstream` directly.  You must open or create the file with the
  necessary options for full transactional integrity (`O_SYNC` as
  a flag to `open` under Unix).  You must write each record as
  a single `write` request to the system.
- It's always a good idea to have a checksum, just in case.  If
  you're worried about security, SHA1 is a good choice.  But keep
  in mind that if someone has access to the file, and wants to
  intentionally change it, they can recalculate the SHA1 and
  insert the new value as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. I'll try to apply it. Thank you very much

Comment: for the checksum... the file is crypted ( with the digest ) so I think I haven't to worry about malicious change.

Comment: For comfortable editing; XML to Binary and / or vice versa. This will speed up the debugging process. Still, the binary file format doesn't seem like a time-saving solution.

Answer (score 15):

All files are binary; the data within them is a binary representation of some information.  If you have to store a large amount of text then the file will contain the binary representation of that text.  The difference between a "binary file" and a "text file" is that creating the latter involves converting data to a text form before saving it.  This is typically done so humans can read it.

The distinction between binary and text is usually made when storing data that is for computer consumption.  Typically this data would *not* be text - it might be a list of numerical configuration values, for example: `1, 2, 3`.

If you stored this in text format, your file could contain a list of human-readable numbers, and if you opened the file in Notepad you might see one number per line.  But what you're actually saving here is not the binary values `1, 2, 3` - you're saving a string `"1\n2\n3\n"`.  Note that this string is 6 characters long, and the binary values (assuming ASCI) would actually be `49, 10, 50, 10, 51, 10`!

If the same data were stored in binary format, you would store the numbers in the smallest useful space, and write the file as individual bytes that can often only be read by the code that created them.  Opening this file in Notepad would likely display junk characters, because the data makes no sense as text.  In this case you would be saving a byte array with actual values `{ 1, 2, 3 }` - or even a single byte with the three values embedded.  This could be much smaller than the human-readable equivalent.

Comment: From what he's said, all of his data is text anyway, so a binary format is likely to be slightly bigger (since it will require something to say that what follows is text).  On the other hand, he mentions encryption: after encryption, he's just got a raw stream of bytes, and any attempt to convert it to text _will_ increase the size, and will not make it any more readable.

Comment: Yes, the encryption is a fairly large requirement to drop in after people have answered :-)  I'll leave my answer here for reference, though it's clear that the actual question is a fair way from that originally posted.

Comment: Re encryption, it certainly changes the balance between binary and text.

Answer (score 5):

Binary files store a sequence of bytes like all other files. You can store numeric values like integers per 4 bytes, characters per single byte, or even serialized class objects and anything you want.

When you know how to read a binary file (ie. you know what is stored in it) you can extract all the information from it. However, text files use text encodings like UTF8, ANSI etc. and they are intended to encode text characters to be processed by text editors.

Answer (score 2):

Binary files are for machines only to interpret, whereas a text file, a human can also open and interpret its content.

So it depends whether you want your file to be readable by a human or not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a lot of factors. I can think of two right now:

- Do you require the file to be readable by humans?
- Is compression a factor? A 10-digits number will take at least 10 bytes as text, but might take as little as four or two as binary.

Comment: Re the second pont, a one digit number will take 2 bytes as text (since it will probably require a separator), but might easily take four as binary.

Comment: @JamesKanze Not to nit pick, but you're assuming a one-byte character set, which doesn't work for over half the planet's population.  With Unicode, at least 4 bytes and up to 8 would be required to store a single digit plus separator.

Comment: @CareyGregory All of the usual digits and most of the usual separators are one byte in UTF-8.  And you're not going to write anything else.

Comment: @JamesKanze Assuming he has no need to support CJK languages that's true, but if he does he'll need UTF-16.

Comment: @CareyGregory Why would he need UTF-16?  You'd never want to actually read and write UTF-16 to a file, except if you're sure that the file will only be used locally, on the machine where it was written.  The univeral convention (today---there's still a lot of legacy code using ISO 8859 or JIS) for data transfer is UTF-8, and UTF-8 has been carefully designed so that all of the characters in ASCII are single bytes with the same encoding.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's not hard to think of examples of why he'd need UTF-16.  Chinese financial data, for example, uses glyphs for digits that can only be expressed in UTF-16.  I develop virtual print drivers, and I can tell you that a _lot_ of applications print using UTF-16, especially in CJK languages.

Comment: @CareyGregory There are no possible examples where UTF-16 do the job but UTF-8 wouldn't, given that they both transformation formats of Unicode, and can represent all of the million and some Unicode code points.  A lot of applications may be using UTF-16 internally, given that it is the usual wide character encoding under Windows and AIX (UTF-32 it usual under most Unix), but I suspect that none, or very few, are transmitting it over the internet, where UTF-8 seems to be the standard.

Answer (score 1):

All data is binary. You always need a machine to interpret it for you. Even if the data is compressed like protocol buffers, Avro, Thrift etc, it is binary, and if it is uncompressed, it is still binary. If you want to read protocol buffers by notepad, there is a two step process. Uncompress, and read. In case of text, this step of uncompressing is not needed. Same is case with encrypted. First unencrypted, and then read. Humans cannot read binary (as some commenters are mentioning). We still need notepad to interpret and display binary (so called text).

Answer (score 0):

All data stored in a text file are human-readable graphic characters. Each line of data ends with a new line character.
In case of a binary file - data is stored in the same format as they are stored in the memory. There are no lines or new line characters. There is an end of file marker.

Moreover binary files show more efficiency for memory as they are stored in zeros and one's.